# SQL Join by Date Range

Tags: sql

I'm having a bit of a frustrating time with a SQL query and could really use the help. Basically, I have a table of customer interactions (sales visits), which has a `customer_id`, a `sales_location` and an `visit_date`. I have a separate table that has orders resulting from that visit. Some visits resulted in zero orders while others resulted in multiple orders. The order table has the `customer_id` and `order_date` with each row representing a distinct order.

I need to create a merged table that has a row for every order or visit linked to the `sales_location` where the order originated from. Basically, the tables have been designed poorly and we need to understand which sales locations are producing a lot of orders per customer visit.

What I need to do, and the piece I'm struggling with, is to use SQL to implicitly figure out, based on the `order_date`, which interaction it was associated with for that `customer_id`. For example, let's say we interacted with customer #463 in Reno and then in Dallas, there would be two interactions on two dates. We may have had 3 orders as a result of the Reno trip and one order as a result of the Dallas trip (or none). I need to use the dates of the orders to figure out which sales location the order came from. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you post some sample data and a table design?

Comment: The `visit_date` and `order_date` would be identical for a visit-sale association? Or is it possible that the order was done 3 days later after the interaction with customer?

Comment: If a customer was traveling and make multiple orders on the same day you would have some trouble sorting out what location the orders were made at.

Comment: @ypercube: The order could be done anytime after the interaction with the customer, not necessarily the same day.

Comment: OK, see my answer. You haven't told us which RDBMS you are using. Some do not have `FULL JOIN` so the answer should be adjusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the last visit before the order is associated with an order.

And that no customer visited two (or more) different locations the same day (actually this would show in the results as having both visits associated with next sales).

```
SELECT s.customer_id
     , s.sales_location
     , s.visit_date
     , g.customer_id
     , g.order_date
FROM sales_location s
  FULL JOIN                       <--- replace with LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT o.customer_id
           , MAX(s.visit_date) AS last_visit_date
           , o.order_date
      FROM order o 
        LEFT JOIN sales_location s
          ON  s.customer_id = o.customer_id
          AND s.visit_date <= o.order_date
      GROUP BY o.customer_id
             , o.order_date
    ) AS g
    ON  g.customer_id = s.customer_id
    AND g.last_visit_date = s.visit_date
```

You can replace the FULL JOIN with LEFT JOIN. Only effect will be that orders that can't be asscoiated with a visit (orders that were done without any previous visits of the customer to any sales_locations) won't be shown.

Comment: Will this also list visits that did not result in any orders?

Comment: @Miron: Which dbms are you using? If it is SQL-Server for example, the query could be done more efficiently using "windowing" functions.